# Send enum value as body in Postman

Tags: enums, postman

I'm trying to call my API using postman, but the problem I'm facing is my API is using PUT method which takes enum object as a body..
How can I send enum in postman.. please help.

```
export enum TestStatus {
    allCandidates,
    completedTest,
    expiredTest,
    blockedTest
}
```

this is my enum , I'm using Angular 2.

Comment: in json format..?

Answer (score 10):

With a method taking the enum as the body, the enum value needs to be entered without curly brackets, simply

```
"expiredTest"
```

or

```
2
```

directly in the Body tab (with `raw` and `JSON(application/json)` and an `ASP.NET Core backend`).

Answer (score 7):

Providing you have a method that takes `[FromBody]TestStatus status` as a parameter.

- Click on **Body** tab and select **raw**, then JSON(application/json).
- Use this Json:

  ```
  {
      "TestStatus": "expiredTest"
  }
  ```
- Send!

I think above is your case as you stated: "take enum object as a body". Below are some more trivial ingredients:
If you have a parameter like `[FromBody]MyClass class` and its definition as

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public TestStatus ClassStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then you modify your Json as:

```
{
    "Id": "28fa119e-fd61-461e-a727-08d504b9ee0b",
    "ClassStatus": "expiredTest"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass 0,1,2... interger in the json body to pass enum objects.
Choose 0 if required to pass the first enum object.
Exmple: 
{
  "employee": 0
}